# TextBox Indexof and LastIndexOf

Tags: c#, textbox, indexof, lastindexof

Because TextBox doesn't have a find function, I've created and modified my own version of it to my needs. I've created to functions. One for **Search Next** and another for **Search Previous**

**My problem is that:**

1. If my search term is more than 1 character long and I've searched
   for the term four times, IF on the 4th term I decide the click on
   search previous it goes back to the previous search term and that
   works fine. Now because I clicked on search previous 4 times and I
   went to the 3rd search term using previous, IF I decide to go the
   4th term again using Find Next, I have to double click on find next
   and *then* it selects the 4th term.
2. If my search term is 1 character long and I want to search for a
   character, I type the character e.g. 'o' and it goes through each
   character in the textbox but once I decide to go back using search
   previous, I have to double click search previous button and then it
   goes back and if I decide to search next I have to double click
   again then it searches next.

This might help understand the double click and single click:

http://media.giphy.com/media/3xz2BJgF2DrtcCnP1e/giphy.gif

I've been trying to get this to work for quite a while now and I've had no luck. I have no idea where I'm going with this and before I confuse myself it will be great if someone can help me with this.

My code for:

**Variables**

```
public int startPostion = 0;
boolean passedNext;
public int pos = 0;
```

**Search Next**

```
 public bool FindAndSelectNext(string TextToFind, bool MatchCase)
    {
        try
        {
            var mode = MatchCase ? StringComparison.CurrentCulture : StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
            int position = TheTextBox.Text.IndexOf(TextToFind, startPostion, mode);
            pos = position;

            if (position == -1)
            {
                var TheString = TheTextBox.Text;
                var foundposition2 = TheString.IndexOf(TextToFind, mode);

                TheTextBox.SelectionStart = foundposition2;
                TheTextBox.SelectionLength = TextToFind.Length;
                startPostion = foundposition2 + TextToFind.Length;
                TheTextBox.Focus();

                passedNext = false;
                Debug.WriteLine("1");
                return true;

            }
            else
            {
                TheTextBox.SelectionStart = position;
                TheTextBox.SelectionLength = TextToFind.Length;
                startPostion = position + TextToFind.Length;
                TheTextBox.Focus();

                passedNext = true;
                Debug.WriteLine("2");
                return true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Could not find '{0}' in the document.", TextToFind), ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

**Search Previous**

```
public bool FindAndSelectPrevious(string TextToFind, bool MatchCase)
    {
        StringComparison mode = MatchCase ? StringComparison.CurrentCulture : StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;
        if (passedNext == true)
        {
            int foundPosition = startPostion < 0 ? TheTextBox.Text.Length : startPostion - 1;
            foundPosition = TheTextBox.Text.LastIndexOf(TextToFind, pos, mode);
            passedNext = false;
            if (foundPosition < 0)
            {
                if (startPostion < 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Could not find '{0}' in the document.", TextToFind), ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    return false;
                }
                foundPosition = TheTextBox.Text.LastIndexOf(TextToFind, mode);
                Debug.WriteLine("1p");
            }

            TheTextBox.SelectionStart = foundPosition;
            TheTextBox.SelectionLength = TextToFind.Length;
            startPostion = foundPosition;
            TheTextBox.Focus();
            Debug.WriteLine("2p");
            passedNext = false;
        }
        else
        {
            int foundPosition = startPostion < 0 ? TheTextBox.Text.Length : startPostion;
            foundPosition = TheTextBox.Text.LastIndexOf(TextToFind, foundPosition, mode);

            if (foundPosition < 0)
            {
                if (startPostion < 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Could not find '{0}' in the document.", TextToFind), ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    return false;
                }
                foundPosition = TheTextBox.Text.LastIndexOf(TextToFind, mode);
            }

            if (!(foundPosition == -1))
            {
                try
                {
                    int foundPositionz = startPostion < 0 ? TheTextBox.Text.Length : startPostion - 1;
                    foundPositionz = TheTextBox.Text.LastIndexOf(TextToFind, foundPositionz, mode);

                    TheTextBox.SelectionStart = foundPositionz;
                    TheTextBox.SelectionLength = TextToFind.Length;
                    startPostion = foundPositionz;
                    TheTextBox.Focus();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var TheString = TheTextBox.Text;
                    var foundposition2 = TheString.LastIndexOf(TextToFind, mode);

                    TheTextBox.SelectionStart = foundposition2;
                    TheTextBox.SelectionLength = TextToFind.Length;
                    startPostion = foundposition2;
                    TheTextBox.Focus();
                    Debug.WriteLine("12p");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Could not find '{0}' in the document.", TextToFind), ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: What you need to do is when you change from one search to the other increment or decrement StartPosition by the length of the search term. Them just make the FindAndSelectPrevious the reverse of the other search function.

Comment: @Pedro.The.Kid Thanks for the fast response however I don't understand what you mean by Increment or decrement startPosition? Mind elaborating?

Comment: The first thing before doing a search if(<change search method>) startPostion += TextToFind.Length <-- in one it it + on the other it is -

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic`?

Comment: @Dai it was just converted code from vb.net to C#. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, you should just find all the matches the first time the user tries to find something, and then keep an index indicating which match is to be selected/highlighted.

For example:

```
private List<int> _matches;
private string _textToFind;
private bool _matchCase;
private int _matchIndex;

private void MoveToNextMatch(string textToFind, bool matchCase, bool forward)
{
    if (_matches == null ||
        _textToFind != textToFind ||
        _matchCase != matchCase)
    {
        int startIndex = 0, matchIndex;
        StringComparison mode = matchCase ?
            StringComparison.CurrentCulture :
            StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;

        _matches = new List();
        while (startIndex < TheTextBox.Text.Length &&
            (matchIndex = TheTextBox.Text.IndexOf(textToFind, startIndex, mode)) >= 0)
        {
            _matches.Add(matchIndex);
            startIndex = matchIndex + textToFind.Length;
        }

        _textToFind = textToFind;
        _matchCase = matchCase;
        _matchIndex = forward ? 0 : _matches.Count - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        _matchIndex += forward ? 1 : -1;
        if (_matchIndex < 0)
        {
            _matchIndex = _matches.Count - 1;
        }
        else if (_matchIndex >= _matches.Count)
        {
            _matchIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    if (_matches.Count > 0)
    {
        TheTextBox.SelectionStart = _matches[_matchIndex];
        TheTextBox.SelectionLength = textToFind.Length;
        TheTextBox.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
       MessageBox.Show(string.Format(
           "Could not find '{0}' in the document.", TextToFind),
           ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }
}

public bool FindAndSelectNext(string textToFind, bool matchCase)
{
    MoveToNextMatch(textToFind, matchCase, true);
}

public bool FindAndSelectPrevious(string textToFind, bool matchCase)
{
    MoveToNextMatch(textToFind, matchCase, false);
}
```

Comment: This is amazing! however I do have one more problem, If I add new text, how do i reinitialize the list to detect the changes. Right now it only searches through the text which has been added without the user. If I add any more text and try to search it wouldn't go through them. Is there any code I need to add to the TextBox's textchanged event to detect the change so it can reinitialize?

Comment: Sure. You can easily modify the above example to suit your needs. For example, you can invalidate the current cached search results simply by setting the `_matches` field to `null`. The next time one of the search methods is called, it would be recreated based on the latest text. The above isn't intended to fully implement whatever specification you have (how could it, since we don't have the full specification? :) )...it's just a way to show the basic technique.

Comment: Thanks that worked and it's exactly the way I wanted it to work. Sorry I had taken a long time to test the code otherwise it would have been an instant answer! ;)

Comment: @PeterDuniho I know this is a while back but I'm wondering if you can still help me with something. This works really well however, when I find the text, it jumps to the start of the first occurence of the text and then goes through everything. Is there a way to start the search from the current index of the character and go through? this GIf explins it all, http://recordit.co/W3Hw7ORKFq

Comment: _"Is there a way to start the search from the current index of the character and go through"_ -- it's programming. There's always a way. In this case, note that the `_matches` array is simply storing character indexes. So you can on the initial match, after initializing the `_matches` array, scan that array for the first element with a value greater than the current index of the character, and set `_matchIndex` to that element's index. If you have trouble implementing that idea, please post a new question rather than using comments to try to ask the question.